# Begginner Python Can't run program Syntax Error

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-3.5

First day with Python for school. I can't run a program because of a syntax error. Spent the past 30 min searching and trying to figure it out. This is the error in the console.

```
runfile('C:/Users/Laura/Documents/Spring /'17/BUS4 92/HW/Michael_Garcia_HW_W01_Q1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Laura/Documents/Spring /'17/BUS4 92/HW')
  File "<ipython-input-35-e2b46302466b>", line 1
    runfile('C:/Users/Laura/Documents/Spring /'17/BUS4 92/HW/Michael_Garcia_HW_W01_Q1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Laura/Documents/Spring /'17/BUS4 92/HW')
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

this is the beginning of  my code

```
    enter code here# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jan 31 12:54:17 2017

@author: Michael
"""


def printSpecialToday(weekday):
    print("Today's special is/n")
    if weekday == "Monday":
        print ("Pork Cutlet & Croquette/n")
    if weekday == "Tuesday":
        print ("BBQ shrimp/n")
    if weekday == "Wednesday":
        print("Jalapeno poppers/n")
    if weekday == "Thursday":
        print("Dragon roll/n")
    if weekday == "Friday":
        print("Katsu Curry/n")
    if weekday == "Saturday":
        print("Super Godzilla roll/n")
    if weekday == "Sunday":
        print("Pineapple fried rice/n")
```

Comment: You cannot use single quotes inside a single quote. Either `\escape` it, or – simpler – use "double" quotes around such a string.

Comment: use \' - `'...\'...'` or `" "` - `"...'..."`

Comment: You escape things with backslash, ``\``, not forward-slash, `/`.

Comment: So it's the file name? btw this isn't my entire code. but regardless of what i put it(if i have 1 line of code it never runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your directory name `/'17` must be renamed as that single quote breaks everything.

Comment: Thank you. I never would have thought. I was wondering why the arrow was pointing there. Man never knew the directory name could affect that. Have a great day:)

Answer (score 2):

This is because you cannot put a single quote in between two other SINGLE quotes.

You can NOT do this:

```
var greeting = 'hello folk's'
```

You CAN do this:

```
var greeting = "hello folk's"
```

So for your situation, perhaps double quotes surrounding your single:

```
runfile("C:/Users/Laura/Documents/Spring /'17/BUS4 92/HW/Michael_Garcia_HW_W01_Q1.py", ...)
```